# How to use xml timepicker?

Tags: android

I have dialog button and timepicker created in the same xml code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/dialog_ok" android:text="OK" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
            <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Cancel" android:id="@+id/dialog_cancel" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And then i created dialog in java code and also bring in the dialog and timepicker from xml code as showen below:

```
public void TimePickerDialog(){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.sign_in_dialog);

/////////////////////updated code////////////////////
  TimePicker timePicker1 = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);

   timePicker1.setIs24HourView(true); 
/////////////////////////////////

    dialog.setTitle("Quick Mute");

    //Allow the dialog to be cancelable
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    // Here we add functionality to our dialog box's content. In this example it's the two buttons
    //reference the button
    Button okButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ok);
    //Create a click listener
    okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         //override the onClick function to do something
         public void onClick(View v) {

         }
    });

    //reference the button
    Button cancelButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cancel);
    //Create a click listener
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         //override the onClick function to do something
         public void onClick(View v) {
          //Close the dialog</span>
                  dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    //finally show the dialog   
    dialog.show();
}
```

The problem i have is how do i get access to the timepicker that was created in xml code so that i can make the timepicker 24 hour timepicker? ... and also how do i get the time from the timepicker that is in xml code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like its usually done:

```
TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker)dialog.findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
```

and as usual *this only works after `dialog.setContentView` is called*. Then, to get the time picked, call:

```
timePicker.getCurrentHour();
timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
```

Comment: when i try to get timePicker.getCurrentHour();
timePicker.getCurrentMinute(); it gives me nullpointeexception?

Comment: @john: You are doing something wrong, and can't find the `TimePicker` view. Edit your question to include the updated code and let me know.

Comment: @john: My mistake, the `TimePicker` is found but there are no initial values for `getCurrentHour` and `getCurrentMinute`. You should be checking for `null` on their results. Also, you probably want to access those values when _ok_ has been pressed, for that you will need to make `timePicker` `final`.

Comment: sorry again one more question. i use timePicker1.setIs24HourView(boolean); to get it to 24 hours but the i get nullpointerexception ?

Comment: @john: Are you sure `sign_in_dialog` is the layout that you showed us?

Comment: yea sign_in_dialog is the layout

Comment: @john: Would you update the code to reflect your changes then?

Comment: just updated java file with   timePicker1.setIs24HourView(true);

Comment: @john: You are looking at the wrong place, you call `findViewById` on the activity instead of `dialog.findViewById`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the 24 hours mode in the XML, use `MyTimePicker.setIs24HourView(boolean)` instead.

See [this](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-time-picker-dialog-example) example on how to get the time.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps to get the instance of a TimePicker:

```
  final Dialog mTimeDialog = new Dialog(this);
  final RelativeLayout mTimeDialogView = (RelativeLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.time_dialog, null);

  final TimePicker mTimePicker = (TimePicker) mTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.TimePicker);

  mTimePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
```